# Expected time complexity of an simple algorithm (checking whether is more even numbers in array)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity

With all my tries to find my solution, I got lost in the probability that will satisfy algorithm outputs later on.

The task is to determine whether the given array has more even numbers than odd so that if it's certainly sure, stop the algorithm returning $1$ in case if it is true; $0$ if false.

Best case will be then: $(n/2)+1$ - every iteration we got even number.

Pessimistic case time complexity: $n$ - iterate to the end of an array.

Expected case time complexity: $A(n) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n p(I)t(I)$, where $p(I)$ - is probability element to occur in $t(I)$ (number of operations executed by algorithm on data $I$.

So that: for best case complexity will be: $ W(n) = max(t(I)) $ where $I$ is element data set of length $ n $ and $ t(I) $ is number of operations executed by algotihm on dataset $ I $ .

After many hours of research, I'm left with no other explanation.

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "time.h"
using namespace std;
#define n 25

int is_even(int a[n]){
    int required_even_numbers = (n/2)+1;
    int even_numbers_counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (a[i] % 2 == 0)  
            even_numbers_counter++;     
        if (required_even_numbers + (n-i) < required_even_numbers) { 
            return 0; // if there is no more numbers that will satisfy equation:
                      // even num > odd num
                      // return 0
        }
        if (even_numbers_counter == required_even_numbers){  
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int b[n];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
        b[i] = (rand()%100+1);
    }
    int result = is_even(b);

    switch (result)
    {
        case 1:
         cout << "There is at least half and more even numbers in array." << endl;
         break;
        case 0:
         cout << "Most numbers are odd." << endl;
         break;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout << b[i] << " , ";
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Example: 
Linear data search in array.
Basic operation: compare element with next value in array 
data size: $ n $ 
pesimistic time complexity: 
$ W(n) = max(i) $ from i = 1 to n $ = n = O(n) $ (last element) 
optimistic time complexity: 
$ w(n) = min(i) $ from i = n $= 1 = O(1)$ (first element) 
Finally expected time complexity: 
  $A(n) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n p(I)t(I) =  \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n (1/n) * i = (1/n) *  \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n i = 1/n * (n(n+1))/2 = (n+1)/2 = O(n)$ 

in average half of an list will be passed by algorithm.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Do you need to calculate the runtime complexity of the algorithm you currently have? Or come up with a better algorithm?

Comment: Determine A(n) from the algorithm currently i have, if there is a problem in determining expected time complexity A(n) describe why. For n=10 A(n) should give value in range 6..10.

Comment: What does $t(I)$ represent? You should add any additional details (including your comment) to the original question.

Comment: Also, what does not make sense is that your expression for $A(n)$ does not depend on $i$ but has an additional parameter $I$. Are they same?

Comment: edit: added example, and t(I) representation.

Comment: The best case is $n/2$ steps, before you checked $n/2$ numbers you can never be sure whether the number of even or odd numbers is bigger (or whether both are equal). The worst case that the full list has to be checked. But all this does not matter anyway, since the complexity is simly $O(n)$, if $n$ is the number of elements.

Comment: Indeed, but i need expected time complexity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Acutally post on stackoverflow is deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP statement is somewhat confusing, so first lemme confirm my understanding of the question being asked:

- You get an array of length $n$, where each element is odd or even with equal probability, i.e. $\mathbb P(\mathrm{odd}) = \mathbb P(\mathrm{even}) = \dfrac12$ i.i.d. for each element.
- Your algorithm goes along the array and terminates as soon as you can decide if there are more evens in the array.
- You want an analysis of the expected running time of your algorithm.

Are the above correct?  If so, here is the answer for odd $n=2k-1$.  (The even $n$ case is a bit more tedious, but the same idea applies.)

First, your algorithm $A$ is keeping a running count of no. of evens $n_e$, but it's no different from a modified algorithm $A'$ counting both odds $n_o$ and evens $n_e$.  The logic is easier to explain in $A'$ because it stops exactly when $n_o = k$ or $n_e = k$.

Let $R$ be the running time (i.e. time when $A'$ stops) and let $n_e(t)$ be the no. of evens after seeing $t$ numbers, and similarly for $n_o(t)$.  We have

$$R = t \iff (n_e(t) = k \cap n_e(t-1) = k-1) \cup (n_o(t) = k \cap n_o(t-1) = k-1)$$

Since the two events on the RHS are disjoint, we have

$$\mathbb P(R = t) = 2\times \mathbb P(n_e(t) = k \cap n_e(t-1) = k-1)$$

Now this can be easily counted since $n_e(t) \sim \mathrm{Binomial}(t, 1/2)$:

$$\mathbb P(n_e(t) = k \cap n_e(t-1) = k-1) = \frac12 \times {t-1 \choose k-1} 2^{-(t-1)}$$

$$\mathbb P(R = t) = {t-1 \choose k-1} 2^{-(t-1)}$$

So your expected running time $= E[R] = \displaystyle\sum_{t=k}^n t\cdot\mathbb P(R=t)$.  I'm not sure how to evaluate this summation into a closed-form, but some others might be able to help with the algebraic manipulations.

Comment: P(R = t)  for t=100 will give propability of ~0.07 which is not true, it counts propability for the least number of successes (k-1), but there is also cases where the number of successes may be (t-1). In account of that fact the final propability for t=100 will be 0.47%.

Comment: Example: propability of yours: https://bit.ly/2NHn5XZ and with most number of successes: https://bit.ly/379pHFP

Comment: My $R$ is the exact running time, i.e. exact time when $A'$ stops (and outputs which of evens or odds dominate).  $P(R=t)$ means it stops after examining exactly $t$ numbers.  I did not mean "$t$ or more numbers" ($P(R \ge t)$) nor "$t$ or fewer numbers" ($P(R \le t)$) but exactly $t$ numbers.  This then enables you to calculate the expected no. of numbers examined, $E[R] = \sum t \cdot P(R=t)$.  I thought $E[R]$ was what you wanted, right?

Comment: this one got me really hard time.. sorry for bothering and thanks in advance